# In Sinister Spire's Drow save bonus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures, saving-throw

In the adventure DD2 Sinister Spire all the Drow have an extra bonus on their saves against spell and spell like abilities. Where does this come from? (ie the Matron has +10 and the guards have +3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 3.5, [Drow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elf.htm#drow) get a +2 bonus to Will saves vs. spells and abilities. When *Sinister Spire* lists, for instance, Matron Elessarwa's saves as:

> **Fort** +5, **Ref** +4, **Will** +8 (+10 against spells and spell-like abilities)

you should read this as

> **Fort** +5
> **Ref** +4
> **Will** +8 (**or** +10 against spells and spell-like abilities)

That final parenthetical is referring only to the Will save, which goes from +8 to +10 vs. spells and SLAs. It does not mean that she gets an addition +10 on all her saves vs. spells. It's certainly not the clearest presentation, since they're trying to save space.

The same is true of Muvaysil the wizard and the Dusklorn mercenaries; the bonus they have is just their Will save +2, and it's a replacement for their normal Will save bonus, not an additional modifier.

Comment: obvious when you stop that. thanks.